# OCaml: single-file modules signature definition without using a .mli file?

Tags: ocaml

Using a bunch of generated OCaml files for which it would be simpler to define a top module's signature without using a .mli file the same way it is done for nested modules. For example in Mymodule.ml be able to write something like:

```
module self/this module : sig
... (* contents of the mli file *)
end =
struct
...
end
```

I couldn't find the syntax to do it though. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do the following. I really don't know why this is "easier", maybe you should give a few more details to point you in the right direction.

```
module X : sig ... end = 
  struct
    ...
  end
include X
```

Comment: BTW it's easier as in simpler to deal with half as many files. mli files are relics from caml-light, I wish interfaces could be defined uniformly for all kinds of modules including top-level ones.